# Client can't connect to a DNS server (NXDOMAIN)

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, dns

I'm an IT student working in VirtualBox. I managed to set up a DNS server that seems to work:

```
Server: 127.0.0.1
Address: 127.0.0.1#53

Name: srv-01.lab.loc
Address: 192.168.1.1
```

Now I need to check if a client machine can connect to it. I added this server to resolv.conf, but when I try to nslookup it, what I'm getting is this:

```
Server: 192.168.1.1
Address: 192.168.1.1#53

** server can't find srv-01: NXDOMAIN
```

How should I fix this? Or am I doing it all wrong and you have to do something else to test the server from a client machine?

EDIT:

When I run "nslookup 192.168.1.1" on my client machine, instead of "srv-01.lab.loc" what is shows is this:

```
1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa    name = router.asus.com.
```

And trying to nslookup "router.asus.com" gives me this:

```
Server: 192.168.1.1
Address: 192.168.1.1#53

Name: router.asus.com
Address: 192.168.1.1
```

What do I do to make it recognize "srv-01.lab.loc" as the name of the server instead of "router.asus.com"?

Comment: based on your previous question about dhcp, I thought your client machines would get the dns server automatically. Therefore you shouldn't need to do anything. Show us your exact nslookup command, used on your client machine.

Comment: By the way, your client is connecting to your DNS server just fine, it is the lookup itself that is failing.

Comment: I'm doing this for a university assignment - I have to set up a DNS server manually and test if a client can connect to it, but it wasn't specified how exactly I should test that last part, so I'm at a bit of a loss (since I have almost no experience with Ubuntu). DHCP was a different assignment. Here's the nslookup command: https://i.imgur.com/uOO9nlI.png

Comment: My best guess is that your "search" auto appending part is not setup correctly. So force it manually. Do: `nslookup srv-01.lab.loc` and see what you get. You need to take a step back and learn how to copy and paste directly into your question, so that we don't need to look at screenshots. One way would be to install SSH server on your virtual box computer and connect to it from your main computer, perhaps with PuTTY, Then copy and paste from your PuTTY ssh session.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will try to figure out the way to do it. I get the same thing when I do nslookup srv-01.lab.loc. However I found out that, when I nslookup the actual IP from the client, it shows the name of the server as "router.asus.com": https://imgur.com/8x77VOk , when on my actual computer it's "srv-01.lab.loc": https://imgur.com/a/2PLlstc Why could that be?

Comment: you will have to tell us more about your LAN, your host computer, your actual router to internet and such. In particular, the IP addresses on your LAN (Local Area Network).

Comment: I realized that 192.168.1.1 is a router IP, which is why my client machine got confused. When I changed the IP address for DNS server to 192.168.1.2, everything finally worked. But thank you for taking your time to help me, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the root of my problem was apparently the fact that as an IP address for my DNS server I was using 192.168.1.1, which is a router IP, so my client machine got confused. When I instead gave my DNS server an IP of 192.168.1.2, everything worked perfectly.